# Getting incorrect environment variables in VS Code debug mode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I'm using VS Code's remote feature to code over ssh & am trying to set up the debug configuration. The python program I am running uses a lot of environment variables, here's one case:

```
user = os.environ.get("USER")
```

When I run in debug mode, `user` is set to the string `root` when I want it to be set to my username `tdeng`. I've tried setting these in the configuration file:

```
"env": { "USER" : "${env:USER}"},
```

or

```
"env": { "USER" : "tdeng"},
```

but they never affect the os.environ.get() - it's always `root` for some reason.

I've also attempted this https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/436#issuecomment-361540371 but it did not work.

The program runs fine when I do it in the integrated terminal directly using the same python environment I have set. (`python program.py`), it just accesses all those environment variables normally. Any suggestions? I'm dying trying to find solutions to this on the internet, and I can't tell if this is an issue with VS Code, the remote extension, my configuration file, or my dev environment.

EDIT:
The launch config looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "mia",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "sudo": true,
    "program": "/home/tdeng/a/bin/program.py",
    "env": { "USER" : "tdeng"},
}
```

I am pretty sure I'm running the correct config because I'm clicking the same name in the debug dropdown. The program also runs correctly & is importing the correct modules, etc, up until `os.environ.get`.

Comment: `"env": { "USER" : "${env:USER}"}` won't do what you want. Can you share your complete `launch.json` configuration that you're using to launch the debugger? Are you certain you're using the debug configuration when launching and not another one you have set up?

Comment: @BrettCannon, added some context! i'm pretty sure i am using the correct debug config bc i have it named differently. i've been testing those two ways to set the environment variables, and have tried creating a .env file, but neither seemed to work

Comment: Not sure at this point, so please file an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.

Comment: for reference this bug is now being tracked at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7710

Comment: I experience what seems to be the same problem. I don't use a launch.json, since I let the Python extension detect my pytests. If I then run the tests from the testing workbench, they fail because the environment variables are not found. If I run the exact same test in the terminal, they pass. @TimothyDeng Did you solve it?